# Codeigniter: Redirect not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I've searched through some of the other posts on here with this similar issue, but I haven't managed to make this work. don't know what the problem is.

- I'm trying to redirect to the main `Home` controller after logon/logout from the `Login` controller

I have the `error_reporting(E_ALL)` set in my development environment variables and there's no error and tried loading the url helper in my `Login` controller: `$this->load->helper('url');`

Here is the main `Home` controller:

```
public function index() {
        if (($this->session->userdata('username') != "")) {
            $this->user();
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

Here's the `Login` controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function logout()
    {
                $profile = array(
                    'userid' => '',
                    'username' => '',
                    'role' => '',
                    'custid' => '',
                    'custname' => '',
                    'logged_in' => FALSE 
                    );

        $this->session->unset_userdata($profile);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/', 'refresh');
    }
    public function logon()
    {
        $data = $_POST;
        $this->db->select("people.*, customers.name as 'custname', customers.id as 'custid'");
        $this->db->from('people');
        $this->db->join('customers', 'customers.id = people.customer');
        $this->db->where('people.username', $data['username']);
        $this->db->where('people.password', $data['password']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $results = $query->result_array();

        if(count($results) > 0)
        {
            $profile = array(
               'username'  => $results[0]['username'],
               'userid'  => $results[0]['id'],
               'role'  => $results[0]['role'],
               'date_format'  => $results[0]['date_format'],
               'custname' => $results[0]['custname'],
               'custid' => $results[0]['custid'],
               'logged_in' => TRUE
            );

            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from('hub.settings');
            $this->db->where('customer', $profile['custid']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $results = $query->result_array();
            if(count($results) > 0)
            {
                $profile['contacthtml'] = $results[0]['contacthtml'];
                $profile['accentcolor'] = $results[0]['accentcolor'];
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata($profile);
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }else{
            redirect('/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

All I'm getting is the url `http://localhost:85/login/logon` and a blank screen.
I've also tried: `redirect('/home', 'refresh');`, `redirect('/home');`, `redirect('home', 'refresh');`, `redirect('home/', 'refresh');`, `redirect('/home/', 'refresh');`

EDIT:

This is the response from Network section in dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `count($results)` is `> 0`  ? Because `redirect("home")` should be enough. (On a side note, you shouldn't have queries in your controller, they belong to models)

Comment: yes, I've just checked the `&results` variable inside the if, it has values (on your side note, its for simplicity)

Comment: if you place `die("hello");` instead of your redirect("home"), do you see hello ?

Comment: how is set your base_url in your config file ?

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost:85';`

Comment: You forgot the trailing slash : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:85/';`

Comment: @AdrienXL: yeey, thanks AdrienXL, that solved it, you should post the answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the base_url in the config file must be set with a trailing slash. In your case :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:85/';
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to a Chrome redirect problem, as stated here http://forums.asp.net/t/1599598.aspx?Response+Redirect+problem+in+Google+Chrome. 
You should try other browsers to be sure. If so, then you should clear Chrome cache.